# solve the equation for x

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Hi i have a homework to solve an equation for x and i have been trying to solve this for an hour and got confused. Please help me with it and Thank you. it would be great if it is step by step.

$-4 x \sqrt{x} (x^2 - 1)^{-3} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(x^2 + 1)^{-2}=0$

Comment: Hello, I've changed your statement of the problem to LaTeX code, which I would recommend learning to get the most out of this site. Can you check to make sure that I've translated correctly?

Comment: You need to post what you have tried, and where you got stuck.

Comment: "i have been trying to solve this for an hour and got confused" - where are you confused?

Comment: this is where i got stuck:
(x^2-1)^3-8x^2*(x^2+1)^2=0

Comment: Let $t=x^2$.  This will give you a cubic, but it's not a "nice" one...

Answer (score 1):

If $x\neq-1,0,1$
$$-4 x \sqrt{x} (x^2 - 1)^{-3} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(x^2 + 1)^{-2}=0 \iff 7x^8+19x^4+5x^2=-1$$

There are no solutions on $\mathbb{R}$ since all the powers are even and the coefficients $>0$.

Answer (score 0):

We assume $x^2 \pm 1 \neq 0$ and $x \neq 0$. Multiply the equation by $2\sqrt{x}(x^2 - 1)^3(x^2 + 1)^2$. Then one perfectly acceptable method to solve the resulting equation is to expand and apply the rational root theorem and long division to find the roots of the polynomial on the left. Following this, you will quickly see that there are no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$ to the equation. Note that because the resulting polynomial is
$$f(x) = 7x^8 + 19x^4 + 5x^2 + 1\,,$$
the rational root theorem dictates that the only possible rational roots are $\pm \frac{1}{7}, \pm 1$. Thus, these are the only roots that we need to check to show that the equation has no rational solutions. In other words, verifying that $f(-\frac{1}{7}) \neq 0$ and $f(\frac{1}{7}) \neq 0$ and $f(-1) \neq 0$ and $f(1) \neq 0$ proves that there are no rational roots. If you're looking for any roots, it may be easiest to use a computer, which will show that there no real solutions in general to the equation.
You can also notice that, rearranging the equation $f(x) = 0$, we have
$$7x^8 + 19x^4 + 5x^2 = -1 \,,$$
and that $7x^8 + 19x^4 + 5x^2 > 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so that there are no real solutions to the equation.

Comment: well i kinda did that and stuck like this
(x^2-1)^3-8x^2*(x^2+1)^2=0

Comment: See my edit @Orgilbaatar